# Connection from windows frontend .net application to linux server

Tags: .net, linux, windows, frontend

I have the following environment:

Front end application written in .net is running on windows OS.

The forms in .net collects data and transfer it to a linux server.

The data is processed and returned back to the frontend application which shows it to the user in Windows OS.

Please give me the details of architecture and tools I should use in both windows and linux systems to carry out this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate [inter process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

The sample you have provided seems to be under [distributed computing environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Computing_Environment) category.
Distributed computing requires information to be exchanged among independent processes.
[image]

To establishing the communication three concepts need to be agreed upon:
**Operations :** Application programming interface (API) which allows IPC to be programmed at a higher level of abstraction.(eg. WSDL, CORBA IDL)
**Data Representation :** Different computers may have different internal storage format for the same data type, a standard data format representation would be necessary.(eg. XML, JSON, Sun XDR)
**Communication protocol :** When messages are exchanged through a computer network communication protocol is a system of digital rules for message exchange within or between computers. (eg. TCP, HTTP) 

 
Publicly the communication between  a c# client to java host process is done by [web-services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_services), also it is possible to implement the communication throw other standard or custom implementations.
There is no exact answer to your question, I just tried to point you toward the high view of the concept.